# Print string from excel file - receiving error: KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Interface'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to copy what he is doing in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhpTn6JSP9k&t=607s

For that reason I made an Excel file called "testexelfile.xlsx".

It contains the following, with no special configuration of the Excel file:

```
Model   Name        Interface   Ziel
Model1  Fortigate1  G1          Switch1
Model1  Fortigate1  G2          Switch2
Model1  Fortigate1  G3          Switch3
Model1  Fortigate1  G4          Switch4
Model1  Fortigate1  G5          Switch5
```

My code is as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "testexelfile.xlsx"
xldata = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name= "Sheet1")

#xl_value1 = xldata["Ziel"][2]
#print(xl_value1)

xldata.set_index("Interface",inplace=True)

xl_value = xldata["Ziel"]["Interface"]
print(xl_value)
```

But i receive the following error:

```
C:\UserData\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Documents>python blabla.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Interface'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UserData\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Documents\blabla.py", line 11, in <module>
    xl_value = xldata["Ziel"]["Interface"]
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Interface'
```

It seems to me that it can´t read the Excel file. As per this article (https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/) it cannot find the keyword in the directory (which I guess is the Excel file).

In the mentioned article it is described to get rid of the KeyError with the .get() keyword. What I do not understand is how I would implement this in my code.

Would be nice to get a little help as I am still very nooby in programing :)

Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in this tutorial he calls `set_index()` so that he can reference rows by the text in the column using the code `xldata["ColTitle"]["RowTitle2"]`. But you're passing the names of two different columns! You probably mean something like `xl_value = xldata["Ziel"]["G2"]`.

> In the mentioned article it is described to ged rid of the KeyError with the `.get()` keyword. What i do not understand is how i would implement this in my code.

Using `.get()` like this is the wrong solution. The advantage of `.get()` is that if the key does not exist, you will get some other object back instead of an error. This is the wrong solution in this situtation, because you want to use a key which *does* exist. If you use `.get()`, it will prevent the error, but the output will not be correct.

---

Instead, you need to change what key you use. One thing that you can do which is helpful to understand what keys you are allowed to provide is to print out the value of the Series. Example:

```
print(xldata["Ziel"])
```

This will print out the index (Interface column) and the column you select (Ziel column.) The only keys you are allowed to use are the values in the index.

Also, it is important to know that there are two kinds of Pandas objects, Dataframe and Series. The difference between them is that a Dataframe is two dimensional, and a Series is one dimensional.

Here is a good tutorial for how to get data out of a Pandas object: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now i understand the syntax better. I will look into the tutorial.